# How to find a replacement MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, repair

I have a small, dead power supply for a camera battery charger (cheap replacement, no brand name). I opened it up and discovered that one of the MOSFETs is burned out. The datasheet (in chinese) is at http://pdf.peidan.cn/BCB/cs1n60f.pdf . I'd like to try and replace it, perhaps with something with a better heatsink. What are the key specs that I need to look out for, and which specs is it ok to improve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look for improvements of the following parameters:

- Id = 1 A (more is better)
- **Rds(on) = 10.5 Ohm (less is better)**
- Idm = 4 Amps - (More is better)

The following parameters should remain similar:

- Vgs(th) = 2-4 Volts - Less than 2 Volt minimum is good, but not necessary
- Vdss = 600 Volts - More is not needed, could perhaps go down to 400 Volts
- **t<sub>d(on)</sub>, t<sub>rise</sub>, t<sub>fall</sub>, t<sub>d(off)</sub>** should remain similar or slightly lower than in the existing part's datasheet.

Of these parameters, **lowering the Rds will benefit you the most**, resulting in less heat generated.

Based on the above suggestions, locating a suitable power MOSFET on a vendor's parametric search (such as on [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com)) should be easy.

---

**Update:** Reasoning behind key recommendations above:

- **I<sub>d</sub>**, more is better: The existing MOSFET may have blown due to excessive current, beyond the specifications. Having more margin for error will reduce the likelihood.
- **R<sub>ds(on)</sub>**, less is better: The higher the on resistance, the more power (as heat) the MOSFET would need to while passing current - Power P = I^2 * R. Really hot = grilled MOSFET, medium-rare to well done.
- **I<sub>dm</sub>**, more is better: Similar to I<sub>d</sub> above, other than in some circuit designs, the constraining factor is not sustained current, but current spikes going beyond the I<sub>d</sub> value but staying within the maximum intermittent current permissible. If this maximum was exceeded at some point during operation, such as due to a main power line voltage surge, that may have been responsible for the component failure.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of thing I'm looking for. Are changes to some of those values (thinking voltage or resistance) likely to change the output of the charger, and could I replace the appropriate resistors with higher/lower valued ones to fix that?

Comment: @naught101 The reduction if Rds(on) is extremely unlikely to adversely impact operation: Power MOSFETs used for switching typically run in the plateau part of the graph, so there's no careful voltage / current tuning needed. The only other factor to watch out for is switching speed - I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: It'd be great, if you (or someone) has time, to add reasons *why* those higher/lower values are better.